# Compilation failure because of Lombok

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, lombok

I have a springboot app using gradle as build tool and also lombok.

When I'm running `./gradlew build` command, then the `compileJava` task is failing with many messages related to lombok annotations. Examples:

```
> Task :compileJava
\my\path\ResolverDelegator.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
import static com.business.lunch.dto.OfferContent.builder;
^
  symbol:   static builder
  location: class OfferContent
\my\path\LunchOfferService.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
        lunchOfferRepository.findByLocation(lunchOffer.getLocation())
                                                      ^
  symbol:   method getLocation()
  location: variable lunchOffer of type LunchOffer
\my\path\ResolverDelegator.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
        return builder()
               ^
  symbol:   method builder()
  location: class ResolverDelegator

...

> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

My gradle wrapper is set to use Gradle 6.1
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1-bin.zip`

Lombok version is 1.18.12 and I mention that I have the following entries in `dependencies` block from my `build.gradle` file:

```
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
```

Any idea/suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a known bug in javac about statically importing generated methods. javac concludes that an annotation processor can't 'fix' it incorrectly and just throws out an error.

The fix is to not statically import it:

```
import com.business.lunch.dto.OfferContent;

....
    return OfferContent.builder();
```

EDIT: DISCLAIMER: I'm a core contributor to Project Lombok.

Comment: thank you, removed the static import and the build is passing again

Comment: Ran into a similar problem (in Maven), wat surprised me was that Lobok fails completely, giving lots of errors, but no error actually hints at the problem. Took me halve a day to figure out :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it happened that I had the wrong import. I had:
`import groovy.transform.builder.Builder;` instead of `import lombok.Builder;`

Rookie mistake.